# LINQ EF where with list of class for All

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

**we have set.All(value) in linq, when i use list of long in set parameter everything is ok.**

```
List<long> searchIds = new List<long>();
searchIds.Add(1);

using (ClearWhiteDBEntities cwContext = new ClearWhiteDBEntities())
{
    var adsWithRelevantadFields =
        from adField in cwContext.tblAdFields
        join ads in cwContext.tblAds on adField.adId equals ads.id
        group adField by adField.adId into adAdFields
        where searchIds.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listId).Contains(i))
        select adAdFields.Key;

    MessageBox.Show(adsWithRelevantadFields.Count().ToString());
}
```

**but when i use list of class i get error:**

```
var lstId = new ListIds[]
{
    new ListIds { listId = 1 },
};

class ListIds
{
    public long listId { get; set; }
}

using (ClearWhiteDBEntities cwContext = new ClearWhiteDBEntities())
{
    var adsWithRelevantadFields =
        from adField in cwContext.tblAdFields
        join ads in cwContext.tblAds on adField.adId equals ads.id
        group adField by adField.adId into adAdFields
        where lstId.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listId).Contains(i.listId))
        select adAdFields.Key;

    MessageBox.Show(adsWithRelevantadFields.Count().ToString());
}
```

problem is in where line,
and error is:

**unable to create a constant value of type 'ClearWhite.Handlers.ListIds. Only primitive types('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is quite simple. Entity Framework is not able to produce correct SQL from your query.

You can either get `List<long>` before making a query:

```
var ids = lstId.Select(i => i.listId).ToList();
```

and then use it within the query:

```
where ids.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listId).Contains(i))
```

or try changing your query a little bit (but I'm not sure it will do the trick):

```
where lstId.Select(i => i.listId).All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listId).Contains(i))
```

Comment: thank you for your replay, but you chnge 2nd part in to first part that word well before, i need use class because i need to check listId and other fields. in this way i just can check listId.

Comment: You can't pass list of you class to the query. So when you need to use more fields/properties you have to prepare more then one list of primitive type before.

Comment: you mean i must have 2 or 3 single dimensional list, and check all together? is it ok: where searchIds.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listId).Contains(i)) && searchIds2.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listFieldValue).Contains(i))

Comment: If all these lists are later checked with `i` you can combine them together using `Concat` method **before passing to query**.

Comment: would you give me a link to learn more about this, or an example

Comment: can i ask one more question? in code i use contains(i), how can check: contains less than(i)

Comment: Try using `Any` instead.

Comment: thanks, if you want, put your first comment in your answer for other people.

Comment: MarcinJuraszek: i concat these two list but i don't know how to use in where clause! var result = searchIds.Concat(searchIds2);           List<long> resultList = result.ToList(); any help?